# Get min and max elements for 2 corresponding series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have 2 Series in pandas:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
d = datetime.now()
index = [d + timedelta(seconds = i) for i in range(5)]
a = pd.Series([1,4,5,7,8], index = index)
b = pd.Series([2,3,6,7,8], index = index)
```

What is the best way to get min/max values for corresponding index elements.
Like:

```
min_func(a, b): [1,3,5,7,8] (for given index)
max_func(a, b): [2,4,6,7,8]
```

The only functions I could find in the documentation are min/max functions that return min/max within the series, while .apply function doesn't take the index argument. 
Is there a better way to implement that without manual series iteration or some arithmetic magic (like min_func: a * (a < b) + b * (b <= a), max_func: a * (a > b) + b * (b >= a) )

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combine the series into a frame which automatically aligns by the index

```
In [51]: index
Out[51]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 26, 18, 33, 48, 990974),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 26, 18, 33, 49, 990974),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 26, 18, 33, 50, 990974),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 26, 18, 33, 51, 990974),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 26, 18, 33, 52, 990974)]

In [52]: a = pd.Series([1,4,5,7,8], index = index)

In [53]: b = pd.Series([2,3,6,7,8], index = index)

In [54]: a
Out[54]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    1
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    4
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    5
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    7
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    8
dtype: int64

In [55]: b
Out[55]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    2
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    3
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    6
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    7
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    8
dtype: int64

In [56]: df = DataFrame({ 'a' : a, 'b' : b })

In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
                            a  b
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974  1  2
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974  4  3
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974  5  6
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974  7  7
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974  8  8
```

Min/Max

```
In [9]: df.max(1)
Out[9]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    2
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    4
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    6
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    7
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    8
Freq: S, dtype: int64

In [10]: df.min(1)
Out[10]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    1
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    3
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    5
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    7
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    8
Freq: S, dtype: int64
```

Index of min/max

```
In [11]: df.idxmax(1)
Out[11]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    b
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    a
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    b
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    a
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    a
Freq: S, dtype: object

In [12]: df.idxmin(1)
Out[12]: 
2013-08-26 18:33:48.990974    a
2013-08-26 18:33:49.990974    b
2013-08-26 18:33:50.990974    a
2013-08-26 18:33:51.990974    a
2013-08-26 18:33:52.990974    a
Freq: S, dtype: object
```

Comment: Looking at the original poster's desired output, I think you want to add ``axis=1``.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response.. What would be performance implications compared to arithmetic solution? Based on DataFrame internals, is it more expensive to create new data frame vs a few additions/subtractions?

Comment: this is all vectorizated; it is often much faster to create a new frame than modify an existing; the semantics of pandas are geared toward this and very few operations modify (though some can with an inplace keyword)

Comment: I would like to find max and min for the 15minutes time frame and how to do it.?